# listen to two IPs for hosting 2 websites with SSL

Tags: opensuse, apache-httpd

At my work I had been working on one web application with Apache on opensuse listening to one IP, let's say 123.123.123.200. 
Now we are adding to different web application to same machine. both have their own SSL certificates. 
SSL working fine on one website which was already running there before. 
Now my apache vhosts.conf look like as follows

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost 123.123.123.200:80
NameVirtualHost 123.123.123.200:443
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.200:443>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/domainone
    ServerName      domainone
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /srv/cert/domainone.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/cert/domainone.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.200:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/domainone
    ServerName      domainone
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 123.123.123.201:443>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/domaintwo
    ServerName      domaintwo
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /srv/cert/domaintwo.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/cert/domaintwo.key
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost 123.123.123.201:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/domaintwo
    ServerName      domaintwo
 </VirtualHost>
```

with this config I get an error when I start Apache but if I disable entries for 123.123.123.201 then Apache starts fine.

What I am doing wrong here?

another thing related to same setup is that how to setup Apache to listen to multiple IP. Is it under control of apache or the operating system?

Comment: "I get an error" Feel like sharing?

Comment: just this 
    Starting httpd2 (prefork) failed

Comment: @codescope: nothing more detailed in the error log?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz There is nothing in error_log regarding failing of server start. Is there any other place to look for failure logs?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've forgotten to add `123.123.123.201:80` and `123.123.123.201:443` to your `NameVirtualHost` stanzas.

Comment: "startproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork: 1  - failed". I always get this error. should I start 2 instances of apache to listen to each IP?

Comment: No. Did you tell apache to check your config before trying to start?

Comment: yes. i used "rcapache2 configtest" and "rcapache2 extreme-configtest". i get "Syntax: OK" in both cases. but when I restart I get above error message

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong. I did same steps on winxp+apache and it worked without any error.